# Insert N numbers in a maximum binary heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, graph-algorithm

I have create a data structure that implements a maximum binary heap. Im trying to find 2 sequences of n numbers which the insertion takes O(n) and O(nlogn) time.
Is this possible?

Comment: Insert them in sorted order and in reverse sorted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to restate what you are asking; please correct me if this is wrong.

So a *Binary Heap*  data structure has time complexity of `logN` for `insertion`. The process of insertion in a `max-heap` is as follows,

1. the tree is a complete binary tree, i.e. all levels are full except the last one.
2. insert at the left most spot in the tree.
3. if the node is smaller than the parent, a swap is performed.
4. the process is repeated until the node is at the appropriate level.

So for your question,
you want a sequence of `n` numbers with insertion time complexity of `O(n)`. This means, that each insertion takes `O(1)` or constant time. This means we need a sequence where there is no need for a `heapify` operation. I think a sequence like following would obviate the need for a `heapify` operation.

`[10, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]`

for the second one, you want `O(nlogn)` which means each operation takes `logn` which is the standard or average performance a binary heap for insertion. So any sequence should do,

`[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

for each one from 2nd onward, you need to compare to parent node and `swap`.

Comment: For O(n) it's as simple as `10 9 8 7 6 5 4`. The only requirement is that all nodes at each level are smaller than the nodes at the parent level. A simple decreasing sequence satisfies that requirement.